# Apache Pivot & TabPane - programmatically setting label and icon

Tags: apache-pivot

In version 1.5 of the apache pivot project the TabPane class supported setIcon() and setLabel(). These methods were removed in version 2.0. Does anyone know what I should now be using for these calls?

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.0.x of Pivot, you would do:
`TabPane.setTabData(component, new ButtonData(...));` after adding the component itself to the TabPane sequence (with `tabPane.getTabs().add(component);` as you've said.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the tutorial correctly, it would be:

```
tabPane.getTabs().add(component)
```

where component is a `Label` or `ButtonData` that contains the icon and text.

Here's an [example](http://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/tab-panes.html) of `TabPane` in version 2.0.2 of Apache Pivot.